# Zend mail headers issue - malformed and 'content preview'

Tags: email, zend-framework2, email-headers

I am using zend-mail (updated very recently). I am using IMAP storage to fetch a list of messages with an inordinate (more than half) of the messages reporting a malformed header.

I have reviewed the bug described at: [ZendMail - error in headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32840448/zendmail-error-in-headers) but I think I have a different problem. Unlike that error, my failure seems to be occurring around a 'content preview' line I receive in many messages.

I've added the failing line text to the error statement:

```
2018-01-13T11:44:46-05:00 ERR (3): Error reading message 19 -  Malformed header detected  Content preview:  Pacific Operational Science & Technology Conference - POST
2018-01-13T11:44:46-05:00 ERR (3): #0 /var/www/book2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mime/src/Decode.php(149): Zend\Mail\Headers::fromString('Return-Path: <A...', '\r\n')
    #1 /var/www/book2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Storage/Part.php(112): Zend\Mime\Decode::splitMessage('Return-Path: <A...', 'Return-Path: <A...', '')
```

The source code isn't much to look at, the body of the email follows the code snippet

```
$mP = 1;
$mailServer = new Imap(array("host" => "someHost","user" => "someAccount","password" => "somePassword"));
$eMessage = $mailServer->getMessage($mP);
```

The text from the email follows:

```
message has been attached to this so you can view it or label
similar future email.  If you have any questions, see
root\@localhost for details.

 Content preview:  =============================================================================    
Today's topic summary =============================================================================
Group: canvas-lms-users@googlegroups.com Url: https://groups.google.com/forum/ utm_source=digest&utm_medium=email#!forum/canvas-lms-users/topics
```

To me, it appears that this issue has more to do with the number of blank lines being interpreted as the end of the header or something involved with the'content preview' line. I think the lines in question have been added by spam detection software. If no 'content preview' - email headers process fine.

Any help?

Comment: The problem was related to the X-Ham-Report being added by my provider's spam detection software. Once I disabled the the Spam detection feature, e-mail headers were no longer throwing exceptions in Zend's headers.php. It appears as though the blank line between the X-Ham-Report header and the Content preview is what causes headers.php to complain about malformed headers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a Bug in Spamassassin. The apparently empty line above the Content preview: actually contains one space. According to RFC5322 section 3.2.2 this is a MUST NOT, presumably because there is buggy software out there (and I have seen some) that treats this empty line as the separator between the Headers and the Body of the message (the correct separator is a blank line with Nothing in it).

So Spamassassin it producing emails that do not comply with the established Internet Standards, and that is a big NO-NO.

I would be interested to hear of other examples caused by this.